# SQL create user login not working from one database for other database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two databases on a same server, db1 and db2.
I have one table on db1 named table table1, and table2 inside second database db2
users have login for db1 but not for db2.
My application insert records in table1 and I have to insert same records in table2 on second database.

Now since users don't have access to that database, I am trying to first create user logins.
but executing stored procedure, but it don't create user login. My stored procedure is in db1.

```
    alter procedure CreateUserLogin @userid char(35)
as
declare @s varchar(100)    
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM db2.sys.database_principals WHERE name = @userid)
BEGIN

    set @s='use db2 CREATE USER '+ltrim(rtrim(@userid))+' FROM LOGIN '+ltrim(rtrim(@userid))+''
    set @s=@s + 'Exec sp_addrolemember Role1,'+ ltrim(rtrim(@userid))
    exec (@s) 
END;
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: No. not getting any error. Got below result.                        USE [db1] Go CREATE USER abc FROM LOGIN abc
Exec sp_addrolemember role1,abc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding + CHAR(13)

`set @s='USE [db2]'+ CHAR(13)
set @s=@s+' CREATE USER '+ltrim(rtrim(@userid))+' FROM LOGIN '+ltrim(rtrim(@userid))+''
set @s=@s + ' Exec sp_addrolemember role1,'+ ltrim(rtrim(@userid))`

didn't know this could be a problem.

Comment: Now I am facing another issue while calling stored procedure from my application this stored procedure don't create user login, but execute from sql server it creates user login. :(